# R: Finding frequency per term -- Warning Message

Tags: r, frequency, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

I have attempting to find the frequency per term in Martin Luther King's "I Have a Dream" speech. I have converted all uppercase letters to lowercase and I have removed all stop words. I have the text in a .txt file so I cannot display it on here. The code that reads in the file is below:

```
 speech <- readLines(speech.txt)
```

Then I performed the conversion to lowercase and removal of stop words successfully and called it:

```
 clean.speech
```

Now I am having some issues with finding the frequency per term. I have created a corpus, inspected my corpus, and created a TermDocumentMatrix as follows:

```
 myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(clean.speech))
 inspect(myCorpus)
 TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
```

Everything is fine up to this point. However, I then wrote the following code and got the warning message of:

```
 m < as.matrix(TDM)

 Warning Message:
 "In m < as.matrix(TDM): longer object length is not a multiple of shorter  object length
```

I know this is a very common warning message, so I Googled it first, but I could not find anything pertaining to frequency of terms. I proceeded to run the following text, to see if it would run with a warning message, but it did not.

```
 v <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE)
 d <- data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
 head(d, 15)
```

My goal is just to find the frequency of terms. I sincerely apologize for asking this question because I know this question gets asked a lot. I just do not understand what to change about my code. Thank you everyone I appreciate it!

Comment: Try to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Now we can only guess what goes wrong.

Comment: I can't post the link directly because it is from my Blackboard account through my university that requires credentials. Once I open the link I copy all of the text into a .txt file. I figured this question was a long shot, but thank you for trying! I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to find the frequency of the terms, then try this.

First, I get the "I Have a Dream" speech into a character vector:

```
# get the text of the speech from an HTML source, and extract the text
library(XML)
doc.html <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.analytictech.com/mb021/mlk.htm', useInternal = TRUE)
doc.text = unlist(xpathApply(doc.html, '//p', xmlValue))
doc.text = paste(doc.text, collapse = ' ')
```

Then, I create the document-term matrix in **quanteda**, removing stop words (and adding "will" since quanteda's built-in list of english stop words does not include this term).  From there the `topfeatures()` gives you the most frequent terms and their counts.

```
library(quanteda)
# create a document-feature matrix
IHADdfm <- dfm(doc.text, ignoredFeatures = c("will", stopwords("english")), verbose = FALSE)
# 12 most frequent features
topfeatures(IHADdfm, 12)
## freedom      one     ring    dream      let      day    negro    today     able    every together    years 
##      13       12       12       11       10        9        8        7        7        7        6        5 
# a word cloud, if you wish
plot(IHADdfm, random.order = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just call `findFreqTerms()`, e.g. as `tm::findFreqTerms(TDM, lowfreq=2, highfreq = 5)` .

(The `tm::` is optional - just saying that it is a built-in funciton of the  `tm` package)